# VBA HTML format is lost when message is sent to non-outlook client

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have a macro that parses a spreadsheet and compiles emails based on parsed data. The problem that I'm facing is the visual formatting.
When I use the macro to send the email to an outlook email address, everything works perfectly (html code works), but when I send the same email to, say, gmail web client, I'm losing the html and my email is sent in plain text.
This is what my email function looks like:

> ```
> Function OutlookEmail(SendTo As String, subject As String, Message As String, send As Boolean)
>     Dim Outlook As Object, NewMail As Object, SafeItem As Object, Attach As Object
>
>     Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
>     Set SafeItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
>     Set NewMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
>     SafeItem.Item = NewMail
>
>     With SafeItem
>         .Recipients.Add SendTo
>         .Recipients.ResolveAll
>         .subject = subject
>         .HTMLBody = Message
>     End With
>
>     If send = True Then SafeItem.send
>     If send = False Then SafeItem.display
>
>     Set Outlook = Nothing
>     Set NewMail = Nothing
>     Set SafeItem = Nothing
>     Set Attach = Nothing
> End Function
> ```

Redemption is an email plugin that helps send everything automatically and Message contains HTML and inline-css formatted text.

Here's what it looks like when sent to an outlook client:
[image: http://snag.gy/bSLTp.jpg]

Other than below, it's a simple loop with some formatting.
CSS vars:

```
Dim CSS_p As String, CSS_phone As String, CSS_table As String, CSS_th As String, CSS_td As String
    Dim CSS_first As String, CSS_last As String, CSS_jlist As String, CSS_warning As String, CSS_accent As String

CSS_p = " style='line-height: 16px;color: #666;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px;'"
    CSS_phone = " style='font-weight: bold;'"
    CSS_table = " style='font-size: 14px; text-align: center;'"
    CSS_th = " style='padding: 0 0.5em; text-align:center; " & _
            "border-top: 1px solid #FB7A31; border-bottom: 1px solid #FB7A31; background-color: #FFC;'"
    CSS_td = " style='border: 1px solid #CCC;padding: 0 0.5em; text-align:center;'"
    CSS_first = " style='border-top: 1px solid #CCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; border-left: none; border-right: 1px solid #CCC'"
    CSS_last = " style='border-top: 1px solid #CCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; border-left: 1px solid #CCC; border-right: none;'"
    CSS_jlist = " style='border-collapse:collapse;line-width:1px;'"
    CSS_warning = " style='line-height: 16px;color: red;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px;'"
    CSS_accent = " style='text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;'"
```

Table content:

```
job_list = job_list & "<tr><td" & CSS_td & ">" & account & "</td>" & _
                                          "<td" & CSS_td & ">" & location & "</td>" & _
                                          "<td" & CSS_td & ">" & address & "</td>" & _
                                          "<td" & CSS_td & ">" & work_order & "</td>" & _
                                          "<td" & CSS_td & ">" & description & "</td>" & _
                                          "<td" & CSS_td & ">" & service_date & "</td></tr>"
```

Message:

```
           email_body = "<html><head></head>" & _
                            "<body><p" & CSS_p & ">" & Greeting() & _
                            "</p>" & _
                            "<p" & CSS_p & ">   Our records indicate that we have not received signed paperwork for the " & _
                            "following jobs as of yet:</p>" & _
                            "<table" & CSS_table & ">" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Account</th>" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Store Number</th>" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Address</th>" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Work Order#</th>" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Description</th>" & _
                            "<th" & CSS_th & ">Service Date</th>" & _
                            job_list & "</table>" & _
                            "<p" & CSS_p & ">Please remember to submit the work orders, your invoices and checklists (if applicable) for the jobs " & _
                            "referenced above." & _
                            "<p" & CSS_p & ">You may send the paperwork via:</p>" & _
                            "<ul><li>Fax to (000) 000 0000 or,</li>" & _
                            "<li>Email to: xx@xxxxxxxxx.com (please indicate your crew code in the email subject)</li></ul>" & _
                            "<p" & CSS_p & ">All work orders must be signed and stamped by the store manager on duty at the time of service. If the " & _
                            "stamp is not available, please ask the manager to write that on the work order (and checklists if applicable), as well as " & _
                            "initial the note. Submitting un-signed and un-stamped paperwork, that is not properly filled out, may result in your " & _
                            "invoices being rejected.</p>" & _
                            "<p" & CSS_p & ">Thank you for your cooperation.</p>" & _
                            HTMLSignature & "</body></html>"
            OutlookEmail SendTo:=email, subject:=email_subject, Message:=email_body, send:=True
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a function of the recipient's mail client? [I can configure Outlook so that it only displays plain text](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/141)  I haven't checked gmail but I bet I can do the same there.

Comment: The thing is, if I send this to outlook, then take the outlook copy and forward it to another email client (gmail for ex.), the formatting looks good. It's a strange issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `Message` string, with anonymous data/etc? I don't have the Redemption plugin but I can take a look and see if I can replicate it.

Comment: I added message and variable data to the original post. Other than that it's just basic sheet manipulation and some more unrelated to the problem code.

Comment: Ok I'll try to look at it tonight!

Comment: I ran this from Excel, and sent to my Gmail and my work/Outlook accounts.  Both of them look correct; here is gmail: http://imgur.com/BHaOEyF  If you run it **without** using the REdemption plugin, does it perform as expected? If so, I think you can say that Redemption is the problem, perhaps something their tech support can assist you with?

Comment: have you tried to set  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

Comment: If you look at the message in the Sent Items folder with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button), is UserTnef named property set to true?

Comment: Tried forcing the MailItem body format to HTML after you created it? `NewMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` before `SafeItem.Item = NewMail`

Comment: Hm, it must be Redemption then. The problem is that without Redemption email part is not fully automated, you still have to click some sort of a confirmation box, and doing that for hundreds of emails sucks. Almost forgot, yet I have BodyFormat set to value 2 (olFormatHTML constant value) Thanks for helping figure this out.

Comment: Did you solve this, And if so post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to set the body format of the email msg to HTML, Outlook is really good at autodetecting these things.

set BodyFormat to olFormatHTML Witch I think is the value 2

I don't have redemtion on this machine so I can check but it should be somthing like

```
With SafeItem
    .Recipients.Add SendTo
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .subject = subject
    .HTMLBody = Message
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' or the value 2
End With
```